# Why is the CSS in my sub-theme not working?

Tags: theming, 9

I'm a Drupal newbie, but hoping someone can assist. The site was working okay, but I've tried to implement a sub-theme and things seem to have gotten messed up.

What I was trying to achieve is to include my own CSS/JS files, and figured that a sub-theme seems like the proper way to do it. Well, I did install the sub-theme, but no CSS or JS from the sub-theme was loading (or referenced in the page anywhere). So, I played around some more and eventually stopped the entire site from loading.

So, now I'm getting "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.", and the Apache error log says:

```
"Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Core\\Asset\\Exception\\IncompleteLibraryDefinitionException: " 
 Incomplete library definition for definition 'global-styling' in extension 'my_theme'" at ..."
```

My theme is called "my_theme", and is meant to be a sub-theme of `awesome_zymphonies_theme`. Went to loads of places trying to figure out the sub-theme stuff, given the abysmal Drupal documentation, but ended up with a directory called "`my_theme`", under `/drupal/themes/`, and directories of `/css/` and `/js/`, with CSS and JavaScript files in each, respectively, and two files: `my_theme.info.yml` and `my_theme.libraries.yml`. Permissions are all okay, and owned by apache:apache.

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache   26 Mar 24 20:30 css
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache   25 Mar 24 20:30 js
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 1300 Mar 24 20:57 my_theme.info.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache   86 Mar 24 20:30 my_theme.libraries.yml
```

The file `my_theme.libraries.yml` looks like this:

```
global-styling:
css:
  theme:
    css/my_theme.css: {}

js:
    js/my_theme.js: {}
```

The top portion of the `my_theme.info.yml` file looks like this:

```
name: My Theme
type: theme
description: Sub-theme of 'Awesome Zymphonies Theme.'
package: core
base theme: awesome_zymphonies_theme
core: 8.x
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9

#Libraries
libraries:
  - awesome_zymphonies_theme/bootstrap
  - awesome_zymphonies_theme/global-components
  - my_theme/global-styling

#Regions
regions:
  header: 'Header'
  primary_menu: 'Primary Menu'
  slideshow: 'Slideshow'
  homepagemessage: 'Home page message'
  topwidget_first: 'Top First Widget'
  topwidget_second: 'Top Second Widget'
  topwidget_third: 'Top Third Widget'
  ....
  ....
```

Additionally, not sure if I need to include the two lines:

```
  - awesome_zymphonies_theme/bootstrap
  - awesome_zymphonies_theme/global-components
```

... or do they get inherited from the parent theme?

So, I guess three questions there really. Any assistance would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Inside themes/ folder you need the custom/ folder, that's where you put the subtheme folder.

Comment: I did that but it makes no difference.

Comment: Check indendation in your `libraries.yml`, leading whitespaces are **VERY** important in YAML files. Both `css:` and `js:` are sub-points of `global-styling:` and therefore must be intened.

Comment: The YAML is not indented correctly.

Comment: Which means what exactly?

Comment: `my_theme.libraries.yml`

Comment: Thanks Hudri. I didn't realize whitespace would make any difference in these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `my_theme.libraries.yml` isn't indented correctly.

```yaml
global-styling:
  css:
    theme:
      css/my_theme.css: {}
  js:
    js/my_theme.js: {}
```